# Accessing return value from bean function using JSF 2.0 Ajax response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2

I'm builiding a scheduling application using JSF 2.0 where users can add items to a calendar then edit those objects.

I'm using AJAX quite extensively to keep the page from refreshing.

The problem I am having is to get a return value from the function that is called using AJAX.

```
<!-- ... form to fill -->
<h:commandButton value="Insert">
   <f:ajax execute="formField1 formField2..." 
    listener="#{myBean.insert()}" onevent="processSave"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

This successfully calls my JavaScript function `processSave()`.

`myBean.insert()` returns the `id` of the newly inserted row in the database

```
public String insert() {
    //... inserting data into database
    id = {id from database is obtained here}
    System.out.println("I have the ID here : " id);  //this works
    return id;
}
```

I've been trying to get this from the response object within JavaScript in the `processSave()` function.

```
processSave(data) {
    if(data.status == "begin") {
        // ation done here
    } else if(data.status == "complete") {
        // more actions done here
    } else if(data.status == "success") {
        //I am trying to get the ID here
        //I've tried looking into data.responseXML, but to no avail.
    }
}
```

Is what I am trying possible using the current technologies?

I think it would be possible to have a field in the page updated using the `render` component of the AJAX call, then use Javascript to go get the value.  But I'm thinking this wouldn't be as clean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. And more easily done with [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/).

Follow [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/loginDemo.xhtml) example, you may find something useful there.

Comment: Is it possible without primefaces ?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you managed to solve it ? btw primefaces link is broken.